# Changing the URL in function for nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am using Express.js in my project. When I submit a form, a function is executed and what I would like is that at the end of the function, it changes the page from index to results.

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('query', function(qCity,qState,qLowPrice,qHighPrice, req, res){
```

I want it to redirect here:

```
  }); // end of socket.on query function
}); // end of io.on
```

I've read on some posts about using middleware but still not sure it's exactly what I want.

Comment: um how do you ping that socket? is that on server or on userside? what is `req` and `res`?

Answer (score 6):

use `res.redirect`

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('query', function(qCity,qState,qLowPrice,qHighPrice, req, res){
    res.redirect('http://yourdomain.com/result')

    });
```

Comment: Ahh 30 seconds to slow: )

Comment: This is what you want.  You can learn more by reading the Express.js API documentation found at: https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res

Comment: When I try this it errors with `res.redirect('/results.ejs')TypeError: Cannot read property 'redirect' of undefined`

Comment: @sewersama do you have a page called result ?

Comment: Yes I do, I think the error is related to res in someway because if I'm reading it correctly it thinks res is undefined inside of the function so maybe i have to make it global somehow or something.

Answer (score 3):

You should just be able to use redirect in express like this:

```
res.redirect('your/path.html');
```

Comment: For some reason it errors with `res.redirect('/results.ejs')TypeError: Cannot read property 'redirect' of undefined`. Any idea about this?